# eclipse breaking inside a class file

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

Everytime I execute my app in debug mode, the execution breaks inside some class file of an external library that I'm using. Even though it's a NullPointerException, for some reason I can hit resume and continue the execution. In case you're curious, I've put the stacktrace below.

My problem though is that I simply want to stop that. It's extremely annoying and happens every now and then during the execution. But I can't find any setting anywhere which will prevent breaking inside class files. How do I avoid this?

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
    Transformer.isRuntimeCode(ProtectionDomain) line: 154   
    Transformer.transform(ClassLoader, String, Class<?>, ProtectionDomain, byte[]) line: 81 
    TransformerManager.transform(ClassLoader, String, Class, ProtectionDomain, byte[]) line: 169    
    InstrumentationImpl.transform(ClassLoader, String, Class, ProtectionDomain, byte[], boolean) line: 365  
    Proxy.defineClass0(ClassLoader, String, byte[], int, int) line: not available [native method]   
    Proxy.getProxyClass(ClassLoader, Class<?>...) line: 504 
    ClearCast$CasterImpl<S,T>.constructProxy() line: 349    
    ClearCast$CasterImpl<S,T>.<init>(Class<S>, Class<T>, Options) line: 313 
    ClearCast.compileCaster(Class<S>, Class<T>, Options) line: 219  
    ClearCast.cast(S, Class<T>, Options) line: 231  
    ClearCast.cast(S, Class<T>) line: 241   
    Runtime.<clinit>() line: 32 
    ObjectFactory.newInstance(String, ClassLoader, boolean) line: not available 
    ObjectFactory.findJarServiceProvider(String) line: not available    
    ObjectFactory.createObject(String, String, String) line: not available  
    ObjectFactory.createObject(String, String) line: not available  
    SAXParser.<init>(SymbolTable, XMLGrammarPool) line: not available   
    SAXParser.<init>() line: not available  
    SAXParserImpl.<init>(SAXParserFactory, Hashtable) line: not available   
    SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser() line: not available 
    XmlParser.setValidating(boolean) line: 93   
    XmlParser.<init>(boolean) line: 83  
    TagLibConfiguration.configureWebApp() line: 210 
    DevAppEngineWebAppContext(WebAppContext).startContext() line: 1247  
    DevAppEngineWebAppContext(ContextHandler).doStart() line: 517   
    DevAppEngineWebAppContext(WebAppContext).doStart() line: 467    
    DevAppEngineWebAppContext(AbstractLifeCycle).start() line: 50   
    JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler(HandlerWrapper).doStart() line: 130   
    JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler(AbstractLifeCycle).start() line: 50   
    Server(HandlerWrapper).doStart() line: 130  
    Server.doStart() line: 224  
    Server(AbstractLifeCycle).start() line: 50  
    JettyContainerService.startContainer() line: 185    
    JettyContainerService(AbstractContainerService).startup() line: 147 
    DevAppServerImpl.start() line: 219  
    DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply() line: 164  
    Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs() line: 48 
    DevAppServerMain.<init>(String[]) line: 113 
    DevAppServerMain.main(String[]) line: 89
```

Comment: This happens to me too. Peeking in your stacktrace, I'm guessing you're using AppEngine as well? So am I. Have you found why this was happening? (I prefer not to solve by filtering...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've added an explicit breakpoint on NullPointerException or a superclass, then it looks as if you can:

1. Show the Breakpoints view.
2. Right-click on the breakpoint.
3. Choose context-menu-item "Breakpoint Properties."
4. Click on the "Filtering" item in the list on the left.
5. In the "Restrict to Selected Location(s)" field, add an exclusion.

Also, there's a global setting for stopping on uncaught exceptions in Preferences under Java>Debug.

Answer (score 0):

I would be more worried about fixing the NPE.  Download and attach the source if possible.